# Whats the Best way to handle multiple iframe requests

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am making a website in which it has multiple iframes nearly around 5-8 and iframe increases too . The problem is that each website in the iframe keep sending data after 1-2 seconds as a result number of requests are alot and sometime website freeze .

Is there any good way to handle this scenerio ? I tried to search something through that i can stop the further requests from iframe but couldnt find any .